# "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" with GET request

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, knex.js

I get this error when I try a GET request on "/strutture" trough Insomnia:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Here's [the repo](https://github.com/w3bpepe/esamigram) (inside the server folder I'm getting the error, I still need to merge it with the React app). I noticed when doing the migration, no ".db3" file got created.

Comment: I think `db('strutture')` is returning a querybuilder object rather than a result from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use promise fulfilment to get the results.

```
server.get('/strutture', async (req, res) => {
    //GET STRUTTURE
    try{
        const strutture = await db("structure");
        res.json(strutture);
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

This will return the correct query results

[image: query result of knex]

Comment: thank you so much! Didn't notice that await missing!